# Nagiosgraph: setting a logarithmic scale for single service check

Tags: configuration, nagios, logarithm

I need to set `y` axis to logarithmic for a single service check.

I've read this can be done:

> Configure this in the configuration file
>   `/usr/local/nagiosgraph/etc/nagiosgraph.conf`
>    For all graphs: `rrdopts=--logarithmic`
>    For some services: `logarithmic=service1,service2`

But I don't know the syntax for providing the correct setting e.g. `service1`.

Is it the nagios service description including whitespace?

How do I then get the cfg to take effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this:

In `/usr/local/nagiosgraph/etc/nagiosgraph.conf` update:

```
logarithmic="BME680 Enviromental Monitoring" 
rrdoptsfile=/usr/local/nagiosgraph/etc/rrdopts.conf
```

In `/usr/local/nagiosgraph/etc/rrdopts.conf` at line:

```
BME680 Enviromental Monitoring=-o
```

Check all ok:

```
sudo /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

Restart Nagios:

```
sudo service nagios restart
```